# NSAttributedString attributes stripped after assigning to NSTextStorage

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nstextstorage

In the code below, I am loading a markdown string in NSAttributedString. One of the feature in the app needs functionality to **convert NSAttributedString back to plain markdown text**. To achieve that, I am trying to find substrings with emphasis by enumerating the `. inlinePresentationIntent` attribute.

In the code below, the NSAttributedString takes the bold part of the string into account. However, when I assign it to the NSTextStorage, the `inlinePresentationIntent` attribute disappears

```swift
let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(markdown: "first **second**")

attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.inlinePresentationIntent, in: fullRange) { a, _, _ in
    print(a) /////////////////// Prints nil and Optional(2)
}

textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)

textView.textStorage!.enumerateAttribute(.inlinePresentationIntent, in: fullRange) { a, _, _ in
    print(a) ///////////////////// Prints nil
}
```

How do I prevent the `inlinePresentationIntent` attribute from disappearing after assigning it to the textStorage?

---

**Observation:**

This happens only with `.inlinePresentationIntent`. If I replace `.inlinePresentationIntent` with `.presentationIntentAttributeName` then the code works as expected

Comment: Is the text view editable? Why do you want to keep the `.inlinePresentationIntent` attribute?

Comment: The textView is editable. I am creating an NSAttributedString from markdown text. One of the feature in the app needs functionality to convert NSAttributedString back to plain markdown text

Comment: Should the `.inlinePresentationIntent` attribute change when the user changes some text to bold?

Comment: Maybe yes. When the user decides to bold some part of the string, I will add attribute .font and .inlinePresentationIntent to textStorage. Not sure how will that work atm.

Comment: Is it easier to add `.inlinePresentationIntent` on the fly instead of when you're going to convert back? What if the user pastes some formatted text? I think `.inlinePresentationIntent` is resolved and deliberately removed.

Comment: The markdown parser in NSAttributedString is calculating the ranges where this `inlinePresentaionAttr` attribute is present. If it is being removed, then how do I determine where these attributes were to add them again?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why only `.inlinePresentationIntent` is removed. PresentationIntent(the one that parses headers and lists) stay intact even after assigning to textStorage

Comment: How do you know where to add `. inlinePresentationIntent` when the user pastes some text?

Comment: You have to ask Apple why `.inlinePresentationIntent` is removed when it is resolved. I'm getting the feeling that `. inlinePresentationIntent` is added for SwiftUI and is not supported by AppKit and/or is not supposed to be edited. I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: User can only paste plain text. They will have to select a text range that has to be bolded(or italicized). When user pressed Command B then the selected text region will add that attribute.

Comment: The project wher I am replicating this issue doest have single line of SwiftUI

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the `.inlinePresentationIntent` attribute into a custom attribute before setting `textStorage`. Use this custom attribute to convert the string back to markdown text.

```
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    static var myMarkdownAttribute: NSAttributedString.Key {
        NSAttributedString.Key("myMarkdownAttribute")
    }
}

let mutableAttributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(markdown: "first **second**")
mutableAttributedString.enumerateAttribute(.inlinePresentationIntent, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedString.length)) { attributeValue, range, _ in
    if let attributeValue = attributeValue {
        mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.myMarkdownAttribute, value: attributeValue, range: range)
    }
}
```